# Facebook app about sharing the activity on github

Tags: facebook, github, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

Is there an Facebook app to share the github activity in the news feed and summarize it in a timeline snippet?

The user should be able to select the types of activity to post in the Facebook news feed.

Twitter integration is nice to have.

P.S.: The Facebook app search currently only returns 1 app "Github repositories" which seems to be offline.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Now I've found the tool I wanted: http://Geekli.st (they want to build the largest community for geeks / developers)

You can link your github account through a button at the bottom of your profile settings.

See the relevant blog post and video screencast for a demo:

http://blog.geekli.st/post/26151413745/from-the-engineering-team-adding-the-post-commit

Answer (score 3):

Github service hook is what you are looking for. You you need an app to Github, not to Facebook. 
I recently made a research on this area, but never tried these modules:
https://github.com/johanbrook/github-facebook-hook

I hope it will work or at lease help you to continue the research